# Nagios check_mk with plugins

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I'm working a company that has a Nagios monitoring server that was set up ages ago and there's no documents.
It uses Check_MK and it seems it was installed using OMD.

We want to install the following plugin to monitor our RDS servers:
https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/*-Virtual-Environments/Others/Check_AWS_CloudWatch_metrics/details

I've tried to manually configure the files with Nagios command and the file with Host and Services but doesn't seem to work at all. We are not using NRPE either.

Anyone knows how to configure the CheckMK to use a plugin (like a script or something) for a host? Or to install those other plugins to be acceptable by CheckMK.

Thanks

Comment: Did you EVER consider looking at the documentation?

Comment: Yeah, I tried and I google that a lot. Unfortunately not everyone is a nagios expert and we need to know where to look at. Anyway, i will mark as solved because the 4th step (section 8.2 in the manual solved my problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***If you need to run this on your monitored end nodes:***

1)
Read the documentation (that page likely exists since about 2012)
https://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_mrpe.html

2)
Read the check man page.

```
OMD_user@host:~ $ cmk -M mrpe
```

3)
If needed, also look into caching to avoid checking cloudwatch every minute - should you not want that. It depends on how often you want to poll the data.

http://lists.mathias-kettner.de/pipermail/checkmk-werks-lvl1/2016-January/002474.html

***If you need to run this only locally on the Nagios server:***

4) just define a legacy ("active") check.
Described at 
http://mathias-kettner.com/cms_wato_services.html in **section 8.2**.

(I would recommend you actually read all of that page though)

5) a very deep howto in case you would need to write your own & want to add a web ui for it:
http://www2.steinkogler.org/steinkogler.org/2016/08/21/check-mk-write-your-own-active-check/